# Pytorch's CrossEntropyLoss?

Tags: loss-function, pytorch

[image]

Can anybody explain what's going on here? I thought I knew how cross entropy loss works.
I have tried with Negativeloglikelihood as well?

Comment: If your actual y values are `[0, 0, 1, 0]`, i.e. not all 1, you are missing the right part of the formula for the cross entropy loss since `(1 - y)` will not be equal to zero.

Comment: yi is 0 for all of those, y = (0,0,1,0), and y_hat=(0.25,0.25,0.29,0.21), so we are only left with one term? Im thinking it must be something with pytorch, but dont know what. That is the only formula for cross entropy/ i think you are confused with BCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, in Pytorch, `CrossEntropyLoss` is more than its name suggests. [The documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html) says that:

> This criterion combines `nn.LogSoftmax()` and `nn.NLLLoss()` in one single class.

This should behave like you expect:

```
Loss = nn.NLLLoss()
y = torch.tensor([0.25, 0.25, 0.29, 0.21]).unsqueeze(0)
y_true = torch.tensor([2])
Loss(torch.log(y), y_true)
```

[Note that, as pointed out by the documentation of `nn.NLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html), its input are log-probabilities, which explains why I added the `torch.log`.